# Bokeh: Changing the frequency of time in the x-axis of a chart

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

The following coding represents a candlestick chart in bokeh:

```
from math import pi
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

mids = (df.open + df.close)/2
spans = abs(df.close-df.open)

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000, toolbar_location="left")

#p.title = "MSFT Candlestick"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p.rect(df.date[inc], mids[inc], w, spans[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.rect(df.date[dec], mids[dec], w, spans[dec], fill_color="#F2583E",     line_color="black")

output_file("candlestick.html", title="candlestick.py example")

show(p)  # open a browser
```

As you can see in this result that the x-axis dates matches March, the 1th and March, 15th, etc. Is there a possibility to increase the frequency, so that the next date is after March, 1th would be March, 5th for example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html) offers several options. In some cases setting `desired_num_ticks` like this could help:

```
p.xaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 20
```

Or you could try for example:

```
from bokeh.models import DaysTicker

p.xaxis[0].ticker = DaysTicker(days = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30])
```

Result:

[image]